# Subreports are not getting printed

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I tried to create a very simple report with a subreport. The subreport was created separately and was embedded in the data group. The subreport separately gives me the relevant data. and the other main report gives me the intended partial data. But the data intended in the place where the subreport has been embedded is not appearing. It is appearing as blank in the output. Can anybody advise ?

Comment: give the jrxml part of your main report where the subreport is embedded

Comment: we need to see more information on how the subreport is added.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not sending the sub report the data/parameters it needs to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is no data to your query in the subreport?

by default in ireport, a report has no page when the query returns no records.

you could setup a NoDataMessage, i have outline the steps in my other [question/post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355126/jasper-report-with-ireport-setnodatamessage-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Today I had faced the same situation using ireport 3.0.0 and Oracle JDBC.

The work around (kludge) was to set at query at the master report: select * from dual.

Yeah, I do realize that definetely is not the right way, but it help me out. Seems that the master (main) report was not open the data base connection, then the subreport that was configured to use the same connection was not finding anything!

Hope that it help someone else...