# JasperReports with iReport: setNoDataMessage not working

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report that contains a pie chart within it. I would want the chart to be shown no matter if the query returns results or nothing at all. Typically you just need to do the *`plot.setNoDataMessage()`* function, however since this is not exposed within `iReport`, I did it within the *`Customizer`* class just as the following:

```java
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();

plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available so we go into this really "
        + "long spiel about what that means and it runs off the end of the "
        + "line but what can you do about that!");
```

However when I run it with no data returning, it is giving me a blank page and `iReport` pops up with "the document has no pages".

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got an answer from elsewhere on this.

Normally if you are *`jfreechart`* in Java, the above code would do.

But if you are doing it within `iReport`, you have to find the property "When no data" in the root report level, set it to "All sections, no detail".  Then your *`NoDataMessage`* will be showing on the chart.

Comment: Further: If no data is in report it would display `The document has no pages` even with blank report.